# Does ActiveRecord find_all_by_X preserve order? If not, what should be used instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I have a non-empty array `ids` of `Thing` object ids and I want to find the corresponding objects using `things = Thing.find_all_by_id(ids)`. My impression is that `things` will not necessarily have an ordering analogous to that of `ids`.

1. Is my impression correct?
2. If so, what can I used instead of `find_all_by_id` that preserves order and doesn't hit the database unnecessarily many times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Use [Array#sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort)

Check it out:

```
Thing.where(:id => ids).sort! {|a, b| ids.index(a.id) <=> ids.index(b.id)}
```

`where(:id => ids)` will generate a query using an `IN()`. Then the sort! method will iterate through the query results and compare the positions of the id's in the ids array.

Comment: I had considered this approach, but it seemed a bit round-about. I'm willing to believe that this is the best way, however, at least short of writing my own SQL query.

Comment: I'm not a SQL guru, but I'm pretty sure you can only sort in a ascending or descending type of way, your sorting goals are a little more arbitrary. Ruby's sort method should be plenty efficient.

Answer (score 4):

@tybro0103's answer will work, but gets inefficient for a large N of ids. In particular, Array#index is linear in N. Hashing works better for large N, as in

```
by_id = Hash[Thing.where(:id => ids).map{|thing| [thing.id, thing]}]
ids.map{|i| by_id[i]}
```

You can even use this technique to arbitrarily sort by any not-necessarily unique attribute, as in

```
by_att = Thing.where(:att => atts).group_by(&:att)
atts.flat_map{|a| by_att[a]}
```

find_all_by_id is deprecated in rails 4, which is why I use where here, but the behavior is the same.