# what is the equivalent of "find_all_by_id" in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an array of ids that I want to find their respective records from the database, using active record query. e.g: `ids = [2, 3, 1]`

now, for me to find all records of a particular model whose id is one of those in the array, In lower versions of rails, I guess I can do something like:

```
Model.find_all_by_id([2, 3, 1])
```

but according to [this post](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17357),

```
These methods were deprecated on 4.0 and removed at 4.1. If you want to
keep sing then you need to include this gem
https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders
```

My question is that is there no way I can do this in rails4.2 without necessarily having to include a gem?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037460/does-activerecord-find-all-by-x-preserve-order-if-not-what-should-be-used-inst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [officially proposed alternative](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders) is `Model.where(id: [2, 3, 1])`.

```
# There are 3 users in the db, with ids 1, 2, and 3
> User.where(id: [1,2,3,4,1234]).pluck(:id)
  SQL (2.5ms)  SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 1234)
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

---

**Please note:**

The suggested (now deleted) `Model.find([2, 3, 1])` is ***not*** equivalent, it will throw an exception if any ids in the array do not exist.

Similarly, the suggested (now edited away) `Model.find_by(id: [2, 3, 1])` is ***not*** equivalent, it only return one result.

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
array_of_ids = [2,3,1]
Model.where(id: array_of_ids)
```

Comment: for me it only returns one record!!